# Send email with reset password link based on project

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have two projects where both of them use same firebase project. My problem is I want forgot password in both of the projects and both of them should point to different url in the respective project. Any help will be appreciated.

What I have achieved?
I have done forgot password for the first project and I get a email with link, for the second project I want email with different link (I am getting same link).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It depends on which of your projects have access to auth in firebase and I would instead prefer to create one more firebase project for it

Comment: It is not possible in a single Firebase Project.

Comment: Hey Frank, I have just returned from the diwali holiday's and I am reading your answer. I will vote once I read it completely and thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one password reset template per Firebase project, so you can't use the built-in template password reset flow to send different emails to different users in a single project. This usually isn't a problem, as the apps in a Firebase project are meant to be part of a single logical application.

If your use-case must use a single Firebase project, have a look at implementing a [custom email handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler), which is the page that the email links to.

If that is not enough, you can take control of the complete password reset flow yourself. This gives you full control of the emails that are sent, but does mean that you also have to arrange how to send that email and all actions from it yourself. For the actual password change, you'd then typically use the Admin SDK to [update the user profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) in a trusted environment.